# How do I Withdrawing ehter from crowdsale contract to my wallet?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, crowdsale

problem: When the crowd sale ends the contract is funded with the ether contributed but it is not sent to the beneficiary address. How do I get the ether out of the contract so that it can be used by the beneficiary (DAO or otherwise).

[image]

Funding goal : 100 ether

[image]

ERC20 Token code :

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.16;

interface tokenRecipient { function receiveApproval(address _from, uint256 _value, address _token, bytes _extraData) public; }

contract TokenERC20 {
    // Public variables of the token
    string public name;
    string public symbol;
    uint8 public decimals = 18;
    // 18 decimals is the strongly suggested default, avoid changing it
    uint256 public totalSupply;

    // This creates an array with all balances
    mapping (address => uint256) public balanceOf;
    mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) public allowance;

    // This generates a public event on the blockchain that will notify clients
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);

    // This notifies clients about the amount burnt
    event Burn(address indexed from, uint256 value);

    /**
     * Constrctor function
     *
     * Initializes contract with initial supply tokens to the creator of the contract
     */
    function TokenERC20(
        uint256 initialSupply,
        string tokenName,
        string tokenSymbol
    ) public {
        totalSupply = initialSupply * 10 ** uint256(decimals);  // Update total supply with the decimal amount
        balanceOf[msg.sender] = totalSupply;                // Give the creator all initial tokens
        name = tokenName;                                   // Set the name for display purposes
        symbol = tokenSymbol;                               // Set the symbol for display purposes
    }

    /**
     * Internal transfer, only can be called by this contract
     */
    function _transfer(address _from, address _to, uint _value) internal {
        // Prevent transfer to 0x0 address. Use burn() instead
        require(_to != 0x0);
        // Check if the sender has enough
        require(balanceOf[_from] >= _value);
        // Check for overflows
        require(balanceOf[_to] + _value > balanceOf[_to]);
        // Save this for an assertion in the future
        uint previousBalances = balanceOf[_from] + balanceOf[_to];
        // Subtract from the sender
        balanceOf[_from] -= _value;
        // Add the same to the recipient
        balanceOf[_to] += _value;
        Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
        // Asserts are used to use static analysis to find bugs in your code. They should never fail
        assert(balanceOf[_from] + balanceOf[_to] == previousBalances);
    }

    /**
     * Transfer tokens
     *
     * Send `_value` tokens to `_to` from your account
     *
     * @param _to The address of the recipient
     * @param _value the amount to send
     */
    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public {
        _transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
    }

    /**
     * Transfer tokens from other address
     *
     * Send `_value` tokens to `_to` on behalf of `_from`
     *
     * @param _from The address of the sender
     * @param _to The address of the recipient
     * @param _value the amount to send
     */
    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        require(_value <= allowance[_from][msg.sender]);     // Check allowance
        allowance[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;
        _transfer(_from, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Set allowance for other address
     *
     * Allows `_spender` to spend no more than `_value` tokens on your behalf
     *
     * @param _spender The address authorized to spend
     * @param _value the max amount they can spend
     */
    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public
        returns (bool success) {
        allowance[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Set allowance for other address and notify
     *
     * Allows `_spender` to spend no more than `_value` tokens on your behalf, and then ping the contract about it
     *
     * @param _spender The address authorized to spend
     * @param _value the max amount they can spend
     * @param _extraData some extra information to send to the approved contract
     */
    function approveAndCall(address _spender, uint256 _value, bytes _extraData)
        public
        returns (bool success) {
        tokenRecipient spender = tokenRecipient(_spender);
        if (approve(_spender, _value)) {
            spender.receiveApproval(msg.sender, _value, this, _extraData);
            return true;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Destroy tokens
     *
     * Remove `_value` tokens from the system irreversibly
     *
     * @param _value the amount of money to burn
     */
    function burn(uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >= _value);   // Check if the sender has enough
        balanceOf[msg.sender] -= _value;            // Subtract from the sender
        totalSupply -= _value;                      // Updates totalSupply
        Burn(msg.sender, _value);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Destroy tokens from other account
     *
     * Remove `_value` tokens from the system irreversibly on behalf of `_from`.
     *
     * @param _from the address of the sender
     * @param _value the amount of money to burn
     */
    function burnFrom(address _from, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        require(balanceOf[_from] >= _value);                // Check if the targeted balance is enough
        require(_value <= allowance[_from][msg.sender]);    // Check allowance
        balanceOf[_from] -= _value;                         // Subtract from the targeted balance
        allowance[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;             // Subtract from the sender's allowance
        totalSupply -= _value;                              // Update totalSupply
        Burn(_from, _value);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Crowdsale CODE:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.16;

interface token {
    function transfer(address receiver, uint amount)public;
}

contract Crowdsale {
    address public beneficiary;
    uint public fundingGoal;
    uint public amountRaised;
    uint public deadline;
    uint public price;
    token public tokenReward;
    mapping(address => uint256) public balanceOf;
    bool fundingGoalReached = false;
    bool crowdsaleClosed = false;

    event GoalReached(address recipient, uint totalAmountRaised);
    event FundTransfer(address backer, uint amount, bool isContribution);

    /**
     * Constrctor function
     *
     * Setup the owner
     */
    function Crowdsale(
        address ifSuccessfulSendTo,
        uint fundingGoalInEthers,
        uint durationInMinutes,
        uint etherCostOfEachToken,
        address addressOfTokenUsedAsReward
    ) public{
        beneficiary = ifSuccessfulSendTo;
        fundingGoal = fundingGoalInEthers * 1 ether;
        deadline = now + durationInMinutes * 1 minutes;
        price = etherCostOfEachToken * 1 ether;
        tokenReward = token(addressOfTokenUsedAsReward);
    }

    /**
     * Fallback function
     *
     * The function without name is the default function that is called whenever anyone sends funds to a contract
     */
    function () payable internal{
        require(!crowdsaleClosed);
        uint amount = msg.value;
        balanceOf[msg.sender] += amount;
        amountRaised += amount;
        tokenReward.transfer(msg.sender, amount / price);
        FundTransfer(msg.sender, amount, true);
    }

    modifier afterDeadline() { if (now >= deadline) _; }

    /**
     * Check if goal was reached
     *
     * Checks if the goal or time limit has been reached and ends the campaign
     */
    function checkGoalReached() afterDeadline public{
        if (amountRaised >= fundingGoal){
            fundingGoalReached = true;
            GoalReached(beneficiary, amountRaised);
        }
        crowdsaleClosed = true;
    }


    /**
     * Withdraw the funds
     *
     * Checks to see if goal or time limit has been reached, and if so, and the funding goal was reached,
     * sends the entire amount to the beneficiary. If goal was not reached, each contributor can withdraw
     * the amount they contributed.
     */
    function safeWithdrawal() afterDeadline public{
        if (!fundingGoalReached) {
            uint amount = balanceOf[msg.sender];
            balanceOf[msg.sender] = 0;
            if (amount > 0) {
                if (msg.sender.send(amount)) {
                    FundTransfer(msg.sender, amount, false);
                } else {
                    balanceOf[msg.sender] = amount;
                }
            }
        }

        if (fundingGoalReached && beneficiary == msg.sender) {
            if (beneficiary.send(amountRaised)) {
                FundTransfer(beneficiary, amountRaised, false);
            } else {
                //If we fail to send the funds to beneficiary, unlock funders balance
                fundingGoalReached = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to call the "safeWithdrawal()" method from the proper address. The "msg.sender" of the transaction with the call has to be the same as "address ifSuccessfulSendTo" from the contract constructor.